# basic concept of HJB equation

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, optimal-control

As known, the HJB equation is

$-\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(t,x) - \underset{a\in A}{sup}[L^av(t,x)+f(t,x,a)]=0$  ,  $ \forall (t,x) \in[0,T)\times R^n$

I understand that $v$ is the value function that we want to evaluate at the optimal control and $L^a$ is the infinitesimal operator that operates on value function. But what is $f(t,x,a)$  here ? Could someone help on this, please?

Comment: It's the right-hand side of the differential equation that governs the system dynamics: $\dot{x}=f(t,x,a)$.

Comment: In cost terms, it’s the running cost. (And terminal cost is the terminal condition $v(T, x)=g(x)$ for some function $g$)